# getJSON returning null phonegap(android)

Tags: android, android-emulator, getjson, cordova

i am developing phone-gap app in android. In app I am calling a servlet returning JSON. Under app code I am calling following method through javascript in index.html

JQuery.getJSON(servleturl,function(data){alert(data)});

When running in emulator the alert is getting displayed, but data is always null. However if i launch the index.html (main application file in phonegap) from browser, I am able to get Json.

same thing happens even if I use $ajax.
please help me and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you sure that the servleturl is accessible from within the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

A little bit later, but I had the same problem today, and I've solved it, so if you didn't sort this problem this would help.

So, the problem is not in JSON or in the phonegap, but it's in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

You should have a tag like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this should allow your application to work with Internet. Without this connection to Internet from your application is forbidden. That tag need to be placed right after the  start tag.

Check Phonegap sample manifest for full list of possible permissions.

hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up (read made the changes to get working under a newer version of node.js) a little tool called [ibug](http://github.com/johnboxall/ibug) that John Boxall wrote that I found useful for debugging on the phone (since there is no real way to do it except debug.log and looking at XCodes console window.  Its basically a stripped down [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), and its hosted on github as [ibug](http://github.com/kriserickson/ibug).  Hopefully it will help you figure out why things aren't working.